# Vue config files. compile once, change file per deploymnet level

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

Our standard process pre vue is based on .net, we compile once and have config files that we change per deployment level (dev, qa, prod, etc).

Deploying our first vue project, using okta for security, which means the config file needs to be available and loaded at the top of router/index.ts.

I started going down the rabbit hole requiring the file, which worked, but the values were compiled in, not loaded at run time

Fetch.then(parsejson).then worked for the values we need later, but i couldn't put all of router\indexs.ts into the then clause.

It looks like the standard Vue solution to the problem is to compile with .env files, and build a separate copy for each deployment level. (Am I correct this is the default Vue "way"?)

I began to feel like I was going too deep rolling my own.

is there a standardized, pre rolled solution that allows the compile once, load at runtime model in vue 2?

is there a standard way to load the file at run time synchronously instead to asynch with fetch or similar? I know asynch is usually the right way, but i need to control the order of operations, and if I put the rest of router in the there clause it doesn't compile.

Don't remember exact error, I"m halfway to trying to convert to .env files at the moment. Pretty sure it failed on :

```
  router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes,
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This didn't work for me,

I wound up following teh vue standard way, which is to use .env files and build a separate build per level (dev, qa , prod).

The files go in the root (where package.json is)

named like
.env
.env.qa

etc

they contain values stargin with VUE_APP and look like this

VUE_APP_comment=this is the dev server version,

you use them by modufying the call to build like this

from:
vue-cli-service build

to:
vue-cli-service build --mode devserver

You can find more information here:

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html